# How to download files from a remote Linux (Ubuntu) Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

How can I download files from a remote Linux Ubuntu server? I have access to this server, but I don't know a convenient way to download a file from there using SSH (PuTTy), for example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try winscp client on Windows platform, scp on Linux platforms and so on.

Comment: Dude, PuTTy comes with `psftp`. On *nix servers use `sftp`.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Os you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/start).

On Linux Os use command-line tool scp like this. From remote host to localhost

```
scp your_username@remotehost.com:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

From localhost to remote host (you have to specifiy the absolute path)

```
scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost.com:/some/remote/directory
```

Comment: For amazon  EC2, use `scp -i key_file.pem username@remotehost.edu:/remote_dir/foobar.txt /local_dir/`.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to WinSCP on Windows: Nautilus will allow you to SSH and browse files like WinSCP.

Hit Places at the top bar > Connect to Server... > Service Type > SSH

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your local OS.

If you have something Unix-like here as well, you can use

```
sftp
scp
rsync
```

If you have Windows, you can use WinSCP or pscp, which comes with PuTTY.